# Rails/Memcached - MemCacheError (end of file reached): end of file reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

My Rails app is using a Memcached server.

from some reason, from time to time, I'm getting `MemCacheError (end of file reached): end of file reached` in my Rails application logs.

any ideas why?

Comment: Did you try restarting the server? `sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart` ??

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `memcache-client`, and that code has been deprecated since 2010, it might simply be a bug that hasn't ever been fixed. The guy behind `memcache-client` ended up coming up with `dalli` (https://github.com/mperham/dalli), which has much better support.

Going into the source for `memcache-client` reveals a couple of things. The only places that could raise a `MemCacheError` with those error messages are `Cache#get`, `Cache#put`, `Cache#add`, or `Cache#delete`. You can find those at (https://github.com/mperham/memcache-client/blob/master/lib/memcache_util.rb) on lines 42, 61, 76, and 91 respectively. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, I can't help more than that, but hopefully that will get you started.